# Use tcl 8.6 with compiled python

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, python-3.6

Requirement :

```
We want to build python v3.6.4 from source and then distribute it as tar so that it can be used in different machine by just untarring it. The built python needs to work with tcl v8.6
```

Issue:

```
Built python is looking for tcl8.5
```

Build Machine : `CentOS 7`

The steps in building are as follows:

```
 - yum -y install openssl-devel wget gcc make tk-devel
 - wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tgz
 - mkdir -p /opt/mayur/python/3.6.4/lib
 - tar -xvf Python-3.6.4.tgz
 - cd Python-3.6.4
 - ./configure --prefix=/opt/mayur/python/3.6.4 --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /opt/mayur/python/3.6.4/lib"
 - make altinstall 
 - tar cvf python3.6.4.tar -C /opt/mayur/python/3.6.4/
```

Next when i untar the above built tar into /opt/mayur/python/3.6.4 in a different machine and run `import tkinter` , it throws the following error-

```
File "/opt/mayur/python/3.6.4/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: libtk8.5.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Through some debugging, I was able to understand that centos support tk-devel 8.5 only. So the version of tk-devel that got installed in the first step was v8.5.13 and so,python is looking for libtk8.5.so.

I saw this post [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239904/how-to-compile-python-with-activetcl-8-6) and change my configure to

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/mayur/python/3.6.4 --enable-unicode=ucs4 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /opt/mayur/python/3.6.4/lib" --with-tcltk-includes=-I/opt/mayur/tcl/8.6.6.8606/include --with-tcltk-libs=-L/opt/mayur/tcl/8.6.6.8606/lib
```

But this too doesn't work.

Can someone give some pointers as to how to build python v3.6.4 and link it to tcl8.6? And how does python decide which tcl to use?

Comment: When "this too doesn't work", is it the exact same error, about `libtk8.5.so`? Or is it a different error (e.g., related to you not having Tk 8.6 in the load-library path, or looking for `libtk8.6.6.so` instead of `libtk8.6.so`)?

Comment: Also, this may seem like a stupid question, but… you didn't mention building Tcl/Tk 8.6, verifying that the libs end up in `/opt/mayur/tcl/8.6.6.8606/lib`, etc., so… you did all that, right?

Comment: yes the libraries work all right..i have them tested..regarding "this too doesn't work",yes it gives the same error which is it is looking for libtk8.5.so

Comment: The problem is that the Tkinter package is using compile instructions that assume that Tk is provided by linking with `-ltk8.5` (or something like that). Binding to a specific Tk version like that does make using a later version rather difficult. (No idea how to fix this, but it is definitely a Tkinter problem.)

Answer (score 0):

For whoever might find this, here's the way to compile recent TCL/TK 8.6 and Python 3.7 on Centos 7.

- Install build requirements

```
# TCL/TK requirements
yum install gcc libX11-devel
# Python requirements
yum install wget yum-utils make gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel zlib-devel xz-devel sqlite-devel
```

- Download and install TCL

Note that building the is required in order to avoid `undefined symbol` errors at python compile time.

```
mkdir /opt/tcl && cd /opt/tcl
curl -OL http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tcl8.6.13-src.tar.gz
tar xvf tcl8.6.13-src.tar.gz
cd tcl8.6.13/unix
./configure --enable-threads --enable-shared --enable-symbols
make
make install
```

- Download and install TK

```
mkdir /opt/tk && cd /opt/tk
curl -OL http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/tcl/tk8.6.13-src.tar.gz
tar xvf tk8.6.13-src.tar.gz
cd tk8.6.13/unix
./configure --with-tcl=/opt/tcl/tcl8.6.13/unix/
make
make install
```

- Download and install Python

Note that you need to indicate the path to the TCL/TK compiled libraries.
You can also set environment variable via `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

[EDIT FROM Kemin Zhou]
if you use the help from the python newest version (3.11.5 at time of typing. ./configure --help).  It instruct you to use the following to environment variables:

```
TCLTK_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for TCLTK, overriding pkg-config
TCLTK_LIBS  linker flags for TCLTK, overriding pkg-config
```

I was able to build python 3.11.5 with the above mechanism
[/EDIT]

```
mkdir /opt/python37 && cd /opt/python37
curl -OL https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.16/Python-3.7.16.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.7.16.tgz
cd Python-3.7.16
./configure --with-system-ffi --with-computed-gotos --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --with-tcltk-includes="-I/usr/local/include" --with-tcltk-libs="-L/usr/local/lib -ltcl8.6 -L/usr/local/lib -ltk8.6"
make -j ${nproc}
make altinstall
```